# Understanding Margin feature in a Strategy in Pine Script

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I have problem understanding how to properly use the Margin function in a Strategy in Pine Script in TradingView.
Can someone explain it in a very simple to understand way. Having examples maybe would help a lot.
I tried understand their blog and this https://www.tradingview.com/script/9Iwinz7I-How-to-use-Leverage-and-Margin-in-PineScript/. Still doesn't makes sense to me.
Can I use Margin without worrying about the Leverage?

This is what I currently understand about Margin and Leverage
Margin = Is the amount of money required to open a position
Leverage = Is the multiple of exposure to account equity

Comment: Margin is just leverage expressed differently. You can find a more detailed explanation, along with an example, in the Margin section of this article: https://www.tradingview.com/chart/?solution=43000628599

Comment: Thank you. Was thinking it is somekind of a straightforward. When I set to 25% Margin was expecting if price just drop 25% then I will be liquidated.